# multiplying factorizes of primal numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, prime-factorization

"We assume that n is an integer shows a multiplication of primal numbers factorization:

\begin{array}{ll}
n=p_1^{k_1}*\cdots*p_m^{k_m} \\ &\end{array}  that \begin{array}{ll}
p_1,......,p_m \\ &\end{array} are different primal numbers
and that 
 \begin{array}{ll}
m,k_1,......,k_m ∈ N \\ &\end{array}

find the number of the integers that divide n (includes n and 1)

I tried to solve it by failed many times

Comment: You should include what you have attempted towards a solution (even if it is a "failure"), so that we can see where you are struggling, and then we can help with those points.

Comment: You could say that i was completly on the wrong direction and i want to get idea about how such a thing can be solved

Answer (score 0):

The number of positive divisors of $n=p_1^{a_1}\cdots p_k^{a_k}$ , including $1$ and $n$ , is $$(a_1+1)\cdots(a_k+1)$$

If you allow negative divisors, the number of divisors must simply be multiplied with $2$

Comment: To arrive at this result, consider which of the prime powers can occur in a divisor.